# IOS: How to list an already installed custom font in my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I am building an app for iPad and would like to use an already installed custom font in my ipad. I have downloaded a custom font (Cabin Sketch) from Adobe Creative Cloud Suite. After installing, I am able to see the font in **General > Fonts**

In my code, I am trying to print all the available fonts in the system but unable to see the one that's already been installed.

Here are the codes I have tried to print the font families.

```
    NSDictionary *descriptorOptions = @{(id)kCTFontDownloadedAttribute : @YES}; // tried kCTFontDownloadableAttribute too
    CTFontDescriptorRef descriptor = CTFontDescriptorCreateWithAttributes((CFDictionaryRef)descriptorOptions);
    CFArrayRef fontDescriptors = CTFontDescriptorCreateMatchingFontDescriptors(descriptor, NULL);
    for(UIFontDescriptor *descriptor in (NSArray *)CFBridgingRelease(fontDescriptors)) {
        NSString *fontFamilyName = [descriptor objectForKey:UIFontDescriptorFamilyAttribute];
        NSLog(@"Font Family Name = %@", fontFamilyName);
    }
```

```
    NSArray *familyNames = [UIFont familyNames];
    for (NSString *aFamilyName in familyNames) {
         NSArray *fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:aFamilyName];
         for (NSString *aFontName in fontNames) {
            NSLog(@"%@", aFontName);
         }
    }
```

```
    QCFType<CFArrayRef> familyNames = CTFontManagerCopyAvailableFontFamilyNames();
    for (NSString *familyName in familyNames.as<const NSArray *>())
        NSLog(@"%@", familyName);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added the "Fonts" capability to your app and selected the "Use Installed Fonts" checkbox?

Comment: @Paulw11 how do I do that? For the record, I am using Objective C and would require all the configuration to be done via code

Comment: You can't do this by code - It is a capability that you need to add to your project in Xcode - Select your Target in your Xcode project and then in the "Signing and Capabilities" tab, click  "+ Capability" and select "Fonts".  Watch [this video](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/227) for information on using this capability

Comment: So I have this test app that I can try, but under the "+ Capability" I am not seeing Fonts

Comment: What version of Xcode do you have?  What version of the iOS SDK are you targeting?  Note that even with the font capability you can't list user fonts.  You have to use `UIFontPickerViewController` - This is covered starting at about 18:16 in the WWDC video

Comment: That is a great info! And yes according to documentation looks like UIFont will not include user fonts. I am using XCode 14.1 and targetting ios16.1. By any chance, do u know if it is possible to get user font via CTFont? Because I am not using UIFontPickerViewController either.  Also can u tell which which WWDC video is mentioning this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250278/discussion-between-paulw11-and-sivan).